# How to "intelligently" delete backup files based on their creation time?

Tags: windows, backup, php, file-management, database

Every >= 24 hours, my system makes a full backup of the (PostgreSQL) database and puts the resulting file into a dir of files such as:

```
MyLifeDatabase 2022-12-01 12;00;00.pg_dump
MyLifeDatabase 2022-12-02 14;00;00.pg_dump
MyLifeDatabase 2022-12-03 12;00;00.pg_dump
MyLifeDatabase 2022-12-04 11;00;00.pg_dump
MyLifeDatabase 2022-12-05 12;00;00.pg_dump
MyLifeDatabase 2022-12-06 13;04;00.pg_dump
```

(The reason I use ";" instead of ":" for the time is that Windows/NTFS doesn't allow filenames with colons in them.)

This quickly adds up, especially once these are all in turn copied to backup disks. It's such a waste.

So I started auto-deleting any and all files in that directory with a "created at" timestamp older than 6 months. But now I have way too many "close" backups, although they need to be taken (at least) daily for the latest one to always be reasonably fresh...

So, basically, I want to intelligently delete files, so that there is only one per week if older than 1 month, and only one a month if older than 3 months. Or some sane rule like that.

But this is one of those things which I just can't think of how I would accomplish. It's easy (but VERY tedious) for a human to look at the file names and decide what to "cull", but to tell the computer the actual process in detail when you barely know how you do it yourself, manually, is... difficult.

I don't need help with the actual code, but only the "theory" of how this is best done. It seems like it should be a common and "solved" problem.

Note: I am aware of the concept of "continuous backup", but every time I try to set it up, I sink back in the chair from sheer mental exhaustion, and then nothing happens; my current backup scheme remains, which is still better than nothing, even though I could lose up to a full day of database events. But even if I ever do figure that out, I would still want to make a daily full backup just for redundancy, or from distrusting the "continuous backup".

Comment: What have you tried and what research have you done?

Comment: @mashuptwice Uh... I have thought about it for countless hours?

Comment: And based on your thoughts you researched how to accomplish your goal, right? What did you find?